# Is it possible to change the legend size in base R (no ggplot2)

Tags: r

Good morning, I was wandering if there was an option (or a function whatsoever) that allows to modify the size of the "legend" square in a plot made with R base.
I've looked up the web, but it seems that I can do everything with my legend but change its size.
Does somebody know if it is possible? If yes, how?

Thank you all in advance,
Peppe

Comment: The size of the box only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? Graphics parameter `cex` stands for **c**haracter **ex**pansion.

```
plot(1)
legend("top", legend = "legend size test")
legend("bottom", legend = "legend size test", cex = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was simpler than I thought, and I'm feeling pretty dump in this moment ahahaha.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a legend of this type

```r
legend("topright",
       legend = c("Var 1", "Var 2"),
       col = 1:2,
       pch = 16,
       cex = 2.5)
```

`cex` manages the size of the legend